# backtrack repository adding to ubuntu 12.04 error

Tags: backtrack, openpgp

After executing

```
wget http://all.repository.backtrack-linux.org/backtrack.gpg -O – | sudo apt-key add -
```

I'm getting an error like `gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.`

How can I complete this task successfully?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I see a long-dash sign near `-O` switch. There should be short-dash, or minus. Do you use automatic patterning?

Comment: Danatela, thanks for your info. can you please guide me to get backtrack 5 installed on my Ubuntu 12.04 32bit

Comment: @AbySP you can't get backtrack 5 installed as part of Ubuntu, BackTrack was designed as a separate distribution.  As well, Backtrack EOL'd, so... (and also, getting help to install Backtrack is offtopic here, but is on topic at [Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com))

Answer (score 0):

go to http://all.repository.backtrack-linux.org/backtrack.gpg
ctrl-a to select all 
mouse to copy (ctrl-c sometimes doesn't work...)

back on your system in shell go into etc/apt dir
sudo gedit backtrack.gpg
paste the contents
save

then in same dir issue command
sudo apt-key add backtrack.gpg
then do

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

(assuming you have added the three lines to the sources.list for backtrack)